# Customise date format in X-axis of a plot of timeSeries date in R?

Tags: r, plot

Forgive me for this basic question. I have loaded a set of data as timeSeries in R.

```
> class(Return)

[1] "timeSeries"
attr(,"package")
[1] "timeSeries"

> head(Return[,1])

GMT
           Overall
2005-09-21  1.8714
2005-09-22  0.2049
2005-09-23 -1.5924
2005-09-26 -4.3111
2005-09-27 -0.2416
2005-09-28 -1.1924
```

When I plot this time series data, it gives me a figure with date as the label of x-axis with format `"2006-01-01"`, `"2007-01-01"`. How can I customise it as `"2006-01"` or `"2006"` or `"2006 Jan"` and how can I modify the frequency? For example I'd like to have a tick every half year instead of every year?

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the label format you can use the `format` parameter (for info about the format options have a look at [this page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)):

```
plot(Ts,format="%Y-%m") # 2006-01
plot(Ts,format="%Y-%b") # 2006-Jan
plot(Ts,format="%Y")    # 2006
```

While for the labels, you can set custom labels by using the `at` parameter, e.g. :

```
# compute the desired dates to show:
minDate <- timeCalendar(y=as.integer(format(min(time(Ts)),'%Y')),m=1,d=1)
maxDate <- max(time(Ts))
datesToShow = timeSequence(from=minDate,to=maxDate,by="1 year")

plot(Ts,format="%Y-%m",at=datesToShow)
```

For more info about the `plot` parameters for `timeSeries` objects, just type:

```
?timeSeries::plot
```