# How to plot date in a proper format in x-axis in the completeness of the follow-up plot in r car package?

Tags: r, date, plot, x-axis

I am trying to plot the completeness of the follow-up plot in `r` but I am experiencing a problem with x-axis in plotting date in a proper format although I put it in the correct format in the dataset using `POSIXct`

My code and sample dataset:

```
Date.Interventon = as.POSIXct('1/27/2017', format='%m/%d/%Y') + 1:40*60
Status<- c ("Alive","Dead","Dead","Dead","Alive","Alive","Dead","Dead","Alive","Dead")
OS.years <-c(11,13,14,13,13,10,13,14,10,11)
data.fu.lorenzoo= data.frame(Date.Interventon,Status, OS.years)

str(Date.Interventon )
library(car)
scatterplot( OS.years ~ Date.Interventon | Status, data=data.fu.lorenzoo, 
             xlab = "Date of procedure",
             ylab = "Follow-up (years)", 
             smooth = F,  # Removes smooth estimate
             regLine = T) # Removes linear estimate
```

The resulting plot is shown below.
I did many [trials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565267/customise-date-format-in-x-axis-of-a-plot-of-timeseries-date-in-r) but I am still struggling.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that it is what you need but, from your dataset, I assume that you want to see the minutes in x-axis, because days and hours are similar to each other.

with using `minute` from `lubridate` package, you can change your x-axis in a proper way.

```
car::scatterplot( OS.years ~ minute( Date.Interventon) | Status, data=data.fu.lorenzoo, 
        xlab = "Date of procedure",
        ylab = "Follow-up (years)", 
        smooth = F,  # Removes smooth estimate
        regLine = T) # Removes linear estimate
```

By using different packages, like `ggplot2` we can produce similar plot.

Before going forward I updated Data.Inverventon to represent different years. Then created yearmonth variable using `as.yearmon` function from `zoo` package.

```
Date.Interventon = as.POSIXct('1/27/2017', format='%m/%d/%Y') + 1:40*60000000
Status<- c ("Alive","Dead","Dead","Dead","Alive","Alive","Dead","Dead","Alive","Dead")
OS.years <-c(11,13,14,13,13,10,13,14,10,11)
data.fu.lorenzoo= data.frame(Date.Interventon,Status, OS.years)
data.fu.lorenzoo$yearmonth = zoo::as.yearmon(data.fu.lorenzoo$Date.Interventon)
```

then you can plot a similar graph like

```
ggplot(data.fu.lorenzoo, aes(x = yearmonth, y = OS.years, color = Status)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  labs( x = "Date of procedure", y = "Follow-up (years)") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Output is like that,

[image]

Comment: Thx for your precious input. Upvoted. Would it be possible to plot both months and years instead of minutes. Regards. Please, if possible, try to upvote my question.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, there is another function which is `as.yearmon`  from `zoo` package. you can change format of your date like Jan 2020, however, when you put in your x axis, we cannot see the month. I cannot figure out why but it only shows year. may be it will help you. If I find solution, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thx a lot. Upvoted. I used it and it makes sense now. ```car::scatterplot( OS.years ~ zoo::as.yearmon ( Date.Interventon) | Status, data=data.fu.lorenzoo, 
 xlab = "Date of procedure",  ylab = "Follow-up (years)",  smooth = F,    regLine = T)```

Comment: I also reproduce the graph using ggplot, maybe it can be better for you

Comment: Thx a lot. upvoted your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, you need separately format the axis.

```
Date.Interventon = as.POSIXct("1/27/2017", format="%m/%d/%y") + 1:40*60
    Status<- c ("Alive","Dead","Dead","Dead","Alive","Alive","Dead","Dead","Alive","Dead")
    OS.years <-c(11,13,14,13,13,10,13,14,10,11)
    
    data.fu.lorenzoo= data.frame(Date.Interventon, Status, OS.years)
    
    
    
    
    library(car)
    scatterplot( OS.years ~ Date.Interventon| Status, data=data.fu.lorenzoo, 
                 xlab = "Date of procedure",
                 ylab = "Follow-up (years)", 
                 smooth = F,  # Removes smooth estimate
                 regLine = T,
                 axes=F) # Removes linear estimate
    axis(2)
    axis(1, Date.Interventon, format( as.POSIXct("1/27/2017", format="%m/%d/%y") + 1:40*60, cex.axis = .7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your precious output. Upvoted. Would it be possible to put only years and months without days, hours and minutes and to align those dates vertically so we can put many dates. Appreciate your precious input. Please, if possible, try to upvote my question.